# Android new Socket error

Tags: android, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a WiFi connection between a raspberry pi and an android device. I am a beginner in setting up WiFi connections but have found some online code which to establish the connection. Here server C code running on the pi:

```
double C[SIZE];
char D[SIZE];
bool bResult = false;

/* if no command line arguments passed, we'll default to 
    these two port number */

int port = 5710;
int dataport = -1;

if (argc > 1)
{
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (argc > 2)
        dataport = atoi(argv[2]);
}

printf("Server, listening on port %d, datagram port %d\n", port, dataport);
fflush(NULL);

Server mylink(port, dataport, &bResult);
if (!bResult)
{
    printf("Failed to create Server object!\n");
    return 0;
}

/* put some dummy data in our arrays */

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    C[i] = (double) i*i+0.5;
    D[i] = i;
}
printf("Server, waiting for connection...\n");
fflush(NULL);
mylink.Connect();

printf("Server, got a connection...\n");
fflush(NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PACKS; i++)
{
    printf("Server, sending bytes, iteration %d...\n", i);
    fflush(NULL);
    mylink.SendBytes(D, SIZE);

    printf("Server, receiving doubles, iteration %d...\n", i);
    fflush(NULL);
    mylink.RecvDoubles(C, SIZE);
}

printf("Server, closing connection...\n");
fflush(NULL);
mylink.Close();

printf("Server, done...\n");
fflush(NULL);
return 0;
```

And here is the android code to connect to the raspberry server:

```
Socket myClient = new Socket("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);
SocketAddress remotAddrr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);  
myClient.connect(remotAddr,10000);
booleanfeedbackconnec = myClient.isConnected();
int feedbackgetport = myClient.getPort();
```

I think the problem with the code is this line:

```
Socket myClient = new Socket("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);
```

It tends to throw an exception or sometimes just stops the application. I have requested the permissions on the manifest file but cant figure out whats wrong with this line

Thanks

Comment: Why do you create a connected socket and then try to connect it?

Comment: The exception message tells you exactly what is wrong here. 'Tends to throw an exception' is not an acceptable problem description. -1

Comment: @David I was not sure which line was actually connecting the Socket. But even if I delete the other, the one I leave throws the exception

Comment: Throws *what* exception?

Answer (score 1):

With this code you connect your socket to the given machine and port

```
Socket myClient = new Socket("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);
```

Then you create an endpoint and try to connect again

```
SocketAddress remotAddrr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);
myClient.connect(remotAddr,10000);
```

Only one of those is enough.

Comment: I tried removing one of of them SocketAddress remotAddrr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.XXX.XXX", 5710);
myClient.connect(remotAddr,10000); but it still throws the exception

Comment: Could you please look at logCat in Eclipse (i hope you use some IDE for Android development), and post us the exception, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) class:

Socket()

> Creates a new unconnected socket

Socket(String dstName, int dstPort)

> Creates a new streaming socket connected to the target host specified
>   by the parameters dstName and dstPort.

If after you are using the second constructor you will call:
[Socket.connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29)

You will get IOException:

> if the socket is already connected or an error occurs while
>   connecting.

Comment: I think an error occurs. I just don't know what error and how to fix it

Comment: @user3193110 did you asked for internet permission?